# Prestashop / Smarty body condition

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, conditional-statements, prestashop

I need to display a different logo on some pages of my Prestashop website according to the body ID and I wonder what is the Smarty code to do that.

I tried `{if $body->id eq 'blog'}src="/img/mylogo.jpg"{/if}`

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the $page_name in the header.tpl file (where you will display your logo) with the var `$page_name`

E.g.

```
{if $page_name eq 'product'}src="/img/mylogo.jpg"{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PrestaShop 1.7, let me tell you that won't give you anything, this is the new variable:

`$page.page_name`